# jQuery ComboBox hack for custom input

Tags: jquery, combobox

I'm using the code for [this combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).

I thought I would be slick by commenting out this part, which would allow text entry beyond unmatched queries.

```
/*Commented out to allow user input
if (!valid) {
    remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
    $(this).val("");
    select.val("");
    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
    return false;
}*/
```

The problem I'm running into with my cleverness is that I can't get this value while validating the form in JS. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got around this. I created a hidden variable:

```
<input id="EnterYourOwnValue" type="hidden" value="Enter New... or Select" />
```

Then I edited part of the jquery combo to save the value typed into EnterYourOwnValue:

```
                            if (!valid) {
                                $("#EnterYourOwnValue").val($(this).val());
                                /*Commented out to allow user input
                                //remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $(this).val("");
                                select.val("");
                                input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                return false;
                                */
                            }
```

OR to saves the selected value into it:

```
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#EnterYourOwnValue").val(ui.item.option.value);
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
```

Now the autocomplete combobox is hacked to be a select or enter your own value in one box!

Comment: Select box with custom input. I hope comments are used in search so people can find this in their searches; I know I looked for hours before I was lead to the combobox which I edited

Answer (score 2):

The code for JQuery UI combobox has been modified since this question was posted and answered.  The link provided in the question still works, but the code there is different from the code being discussed in this thread.

Here is a fix for the new combobox code (as of 9/2/15) that works like Peter's approach.

First remove this block to prevent the custom value from being deleted:

```
this.input
  .val( "" )
  .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
  .tooltip( "open" );
this.element.val( "" );
this._delay(function() {
  this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
}, 2500 );
this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
```

Replace with this block to add the custom value as a select option and set it as the current value:

```
this.element.append('<option>' + this.input.val() + '</option>'); //Add the new option
this.element.val(this.input.val()); //select the new option
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the "invalid" input to the end of the select element like this

```
if (!valid) {
    select.append('<option>' + $(element).val() + '</option>'); //Add the new option
    select.val($(element).val()); //select the new option
}
```

This is only ever relevant if you are using straight text values in your select

I found your code while searching for an answer for this, but after reading your answers realised what I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

Spent ages trying to get this to work with multiple comboboxes.

To get this post to work with multiple comboboxes I had to add this:

if($(select).attr('name') == YourComboBoxName) $("#EnterYourOwnValue").val($(this).val())

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me while working with multiple comboboxes

of course I had to make a hidden input as well.

```
var thisinput = this.element.attr("name");
var value = this.input.val();

    if(thisinput == "YourComboBoxName"){
    $("#EnterYourOwnValue").val(value);
    }
```